# Acumatica API Get Image

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I am trying to GET a stock items' image using postman.

The steps I need to follow are as follows.
Select the stock item using an API call:

```
URL/entity/Endpoint/1/stockItem?$filter=InventoryID eq 'ABC011'
```

With this call, I get the ImageURL field
[image]

Can I use this to get the corresponding image(s) that is linked to the Stock Item?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the image/file by using (per your url provided):

```
URL/entity/Endpoint/1/stockItem/ABC011/files/YourImageName.jpg
```

See sample below in Postman:
[image]

You can review this article on how to attach files with REST API as well:
https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/01/attach-files-with-rest-api.html